# Is a comma required after 'then' at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

In the following example, is it necessary to put a comma after 'Then'? It would be appreciated if you explain the reason as well.

> In section 1, X is introduced. In section 2, Y is explained. ... . **Then** we present the results of Z in section 4.

I know of these two arguments:
(1) An introductory element is followed by a comma.
(2) When 'Then' is used in a sequence, like 'First, ... . Second, .... Then', a comma is not put after 'Then'.
So I wonder if 'In section 1, ...' is considered such a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, there's a comma after "then" because it is an introductory modifying adverb, an adverb that appears in advance of the subject and the verb.

*HOWEVER,* it's becoming more and more common that no comma is put after "then" as more and more people treat it more and more like an introductory conjunction, despite it being as subordinating instead of coordinating conjunction, or like other modifiers of time, which are often short prepositional phrases, like "On Wednesday," short prepositional phrases not requiring a comma after them and leaving the comma optional, which in turn opens the door to not putting a comma afterwards when we opt to omit the preposition, like simply starting a sentence with "Wednesday" instead of "On Wednesday," especially since such examples, whether with the preposition or without, are adverbial, like "then" is.

Moreover, it's becoming more and more common that adverbs of time, like "now," don't strictly require an adverb afterwards, "then" likewise being an adverb of time when it's an adverb, a convention that may flow from the aforementioned, from the fact that "now" isn't followed by a comma when it's used as an intensifier to strengthen a command (e.g., Now stop that!) or to introduce something contrasting or contradictory (e.g., Now I wouldn't want you to get the wrong idea.), or from how "then" isn't followed by a comma when it's used within a sentence (e.g., The sentence "I went to the store then I went home" doesn't employ a comma after "then" or commas around "then," so many people don't see any need for or logic to requiring a comma if they opt to break that sentence up into two sentences, leading them to write, sans comma, "I went to the store. Then I went home." This is as opposed to conforming to what has been historically conventional in grammar by writing, cum comma, "I went to the store. Then, I went home.").

Basically, it's become increasingly such that whether or not to put a comma after an introductory "then" isn't so much an issue of grammar but an issue of *style*. That means that if you are subject to a style guide, which is often the case in academic writing and professional writing, including in simply professional settings, then that style guide almost certainly tells you whether or not to use a comma after "then," such things being the entire point of style guides-- to make definitive rulings on grammar's gray areas and the things grammar leaves optional. An organization that's all about efficiency may mandate omitting that and all optional commas in its style guide, while an organization that's all about tradition may instead mandate using that comma in its. If you are not subject to a style guide, then it's entirely up to you, the only caveat being to be consistent, at least within the same writing, like don't use a comma after an introductory "then" in some places and then omit it in other places where it's similarly used.